# Hyperledger Indy pool openPool timeout exception --->org.hyperledger.indy.sdk.ledger.TimeoutException: Timeout happens for ledger operation

Tags: android, android-studio, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

I have implemented a library that includes the hyperledger libindy sdk Version 1.15.0 and trying to use this library on Android emulator with x86 platform support.

I am getting error in my code, where the pool is to be opened, Pool.openPoolLedger(poolName, config.toJson()).get().

I am NOT using a docker version of the `libindy` nodes, I have built `indy-tutorial-sandbox` and running indy nodes in my machine.

I used IP value in my genesis-file the return value from "make local" command on indy-sandbox
I am using Android Studio 3.5.3 with emulator X86 support

I succeeded to `initApi` for `libindy` and `createpoolconfig` but when I intended to open the pool I get the error.

Also, I could not find the places in the emulator where wallet and pool directories with related files.

It gets the following error:

W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
    A resource failed to call close.

```
E/RelationshipsFragment: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.hyperledger.indy.sdk.ledger.TimeoutException: Timeout happens for ledger operation.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.hyperledger.indy.sdk.ledger.TimeoutException: Timeout happens for ledger operation.
        at gov.tubitak.did.mostar.api.MostarAPIProviderManager$1.initialize(MostarAPIProviderManager.java:27)
        at gov.tubitak.did.mostar.api.MostarAPIProviderManager$1.initialize(MostarAPIProviderManager.java:16)
        at org.checkerframework.org.apache.commons.lang3.concurrent.AtomicSafeInitializer.get(AtomicSafeInitializer.java:77)
        at gov.tubitak.did.mostar.api.MostarAPIProviderManager.getCurrentMostarApi(MostarAPIProviderManager.java:37)
        at gov.tubitak.did.nixar.app.android.ui.relationships.RelationshipsFragment$1.onClick(RelationshipsFragment.java:75)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: gov.tubitak.did.mostar.api.MostarApiException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.hyperledger.indy.sdk.ledger.TimeoutException: Timeout happens for ledger operation.
        at gov.tubitak.did.mostarIndy.IndyMostarApi.initApiLibrary(IndyMostarApi.java:161)
        at gov.tubitak.did.mostarIndy.IndyMostarApiProvider.create(IndyMostarApiProvider.java:21)
        at gov.tubitak.did.mostar.api.MostarAPIProviderManager$1.initialize(MostarAPIProviderManager.java:23)
        at gov.tubitak.did.mostar.api.MostarAPIProviderManager$1.initialize(MostarAPIProviderManager.java:16) 
        at org.checkerframework.org.apache.commons.lang3.concurrent.AtomicSafeInitializer.get(AtomicSafeInitializer.java:77) 
        at gov.tubitak.did.mostar.api.MostarAPIProviderManager.getCurrentMostarApi(MostarAPIProviderManager.java:37) 
        at gov.tubitak.did.nixar.app.android.ui.relationships.RelationshipsFragment$1.onClick(RelationshipsFragment.java:75) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.hyperledger.indy.sdk.ledger.TimeoutException: Timeout happens for ledger operation.
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:361)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1923)
        at gov.tubitak.did.mostarIndy.IndyMostarApi.initApiLibrary(IndyMostarApi.java:138)
        at gov.tubitak.did.mostarIndy.IndyMostarApiProvider.create(IndyMostarApiProvider.java:21) 
        at gov.tubitak.did.mostar.api.MostarAPIProviderManager$1.initialize(MostarAPIProviderManager.java:23) 
        at gov.tubitak.did.mostar.api.MostarAPIProviderManager$1.initialize(MostarAPIProviderManager.java:16) 
        at org.checkerframework.org.apache.commons.lang3.concurrent.AtomicSafeInitializer.get(AtomicSafeInitializer.java:77) 
        at gov.tubitak.did.mostar.api.MostarAPIProviderManager.getCurrentMostarApi(MostarAPIProviderManager.java:37) 
        at gov.tubitak.did.nixar.app.android.ui.relationships.RelationshipsFragment$1.onClick(RelationshipsFragment.java:75) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: org.hyperledger.indy.sdk.ledger.TimeoutException: Timeout happens for ledger operation.
        at org.hyperledger.indy.sdk.IndyJava$API.checkResult(IndyJava.java:92)
        at org.hyperledger.indy.sdk.pool.Pool.access$100(Pool.java:20)
        at org.hyperledger.indy.sdk.pool.Pool$1.callback(Pool.java:52)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.invokeCallback(CallbackReference.java:520)
        at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.callback(CallbackReference.java:551)
```

Answer (score 0):

check that the IPs in your genesis file  are ok and actually reachable

Comment: how do I do that, browser says unreachable ?